# Pop up with everything just like user opened maps herself

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been doing quite a bit of searching here and on Google, but it's hard to think of a good search string.

In HTML, I set the mapInit callback where I do this:

```
map = new google.maps.Map( elem,
    {
        center:     { lat: 52.1, lng: 4.8 },
        zoom:       10,
        mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
);
```

What I expected is a map just like as if the user started a new tab with maps.google.com, with just those things overruled. That doesn't happen. The tab is always a lot poorer than when I start maps 'by hand'. No search box, no right-click menus, really nothing of all these things that I so like.

Is there a way to do what I want, and if so, how?

Comment: Can the people tyat downvoted the question please indicate why?

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps API lets you create a map viewer on your website.

The experience is very limited compared to the maps.google.com and there is no way to get the "full" maps experience, it's something Google still reserves to themselves.

Comment: you CAN get a searchbox, look here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

Comment: That is not the searchbox I was hoping for. The standard Google Maps 'search box' is a real complex smart box of tools.

Comment: Guess I'll need to add a link in my markers' popups to the real Google Maps page so they can navigate and whatever they want to do from there.